# ArcGIS Python Field Calculation says failure during processing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a problem with the field calculator in ArcGIS:

I have:

- A complete table of several states of the world with their specific life expectancies.
- A world map (not yet joined)

What i have to do:

- classify the states in 5 groups by their life expectancies in an extra field in the field calculator.

What i did:

- I generated the following code block:

---

```
def reclass(a):
    if (a <= 50):
        return 1
    elif (a <=60):
        return 2
    elif (a <=70):
        return 3
    elif (a <=75):
        return 4
    elif (a >75):
        return 5
    else
        return 999
```

Expression:

```
reclass(!LIFE_EXP00!)
```

I added a new field called "Field_1" and i took LIFE_EXP00 from the already given data in the table.

But still ArcGIS tells me after every single time i try it, that there was a failure during processing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong, except that it should be "else:" and not "else". Also, make sure that your input and output fields are numeric fields.

Comment: An easier way to do this with only that few classes: Select by attributes for each class and use Field calculator to assign values to your new field. Requires on calculation for each class.

Comment: If you are still getting an error after radouxju's suggestion, can you add it? We need more detail.

Comment: Worth noting, you have also not stated the type for "Field_1" is.  It must be a numeric (short, long, etc.).

Comment: Go to your Field Calculator and type into `Expression`, make sure your `Expression` is set to Python.

    def reclass(!Field_1!)

Then go to your code block and add `:` to the `else` statement as suggested. That should do it

Answer (score 1):

I think the cause of this, and the reason you are also having trouble formatting this correctly in the question, is that there is a colon missing after `else`.

Try this:

```
def reclass(a):
    if (a <= 50):
        return 1
    elif (a <=60):
        return 2
    elif (a <=70):
        return 3
    elif (a <=75):
        return 4
    elif (a >75):
        return 5
    else:
        return 999
```